# horizontally and vertically center mutliple relative divs inside a div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have relative divs acting as thumbnails and change in size when hovering on the divs. The problem I'm having is that the relative divs can't be centered horizontally and vertically inside a div acting as content.

Here is the snippet

```css
    html { 
        height: 100%; 
    }
    body {
        height:100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        background: white;
        color: white;
        position:relative;
    }
    #header {
        height:170px;
        width:100%;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        background: #1b1b1b;
        position:fixed;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #footer {
        height:50px;
        width:100%;
        bottom:0px;
        left:0px;
        background: #1b1b1b;
        position:fixed;
    
    }
    #content {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 170px;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 50px;
        color: black;
        border: 5px solid blue;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    #boxes{
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        top: 30%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }
    #boxes2{
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        top: 40%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }
    
    #box{
        display: inline-block;
        height: 250px;
        width: 200px;
        -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
        transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
    
    }
    
    #box:hover{
        height: 450px;
        width: 350px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
```

```html
  <div id="content">
        
        <div id="boxes">
            <div id="box">
                <img src="" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
            </div>
            <div id="box">
                <img  style="width:100%; height: 100%">
            </div>
            
            <div id="box">
                <img src="" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="boxes2">
            <div id="box">
                <img src="" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
            </div>
            <div id="box">
                <img src="" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
            </div>
        </div>     
</div>
```

How can I center the relative divs vertically and horizontally one top and one bottom?

Thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jms17h8j/3/ looking something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are having is that you are using `width` and `height` to increase your size, but you are using `transform` to center your element.

You need to increase your size also using transforms, with `scaleX` and `scaleY`.

```css
html { 
    height: 100%; 
}
body {
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: white;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    height:170px;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: #1b1b1b;
    position:fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
#footer {
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: #1b1b1b;
    position:fixed;

}
#content {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 170px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    color: black;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
#boxes{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 30%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
#boxes2{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#box{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;

}

#box:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scaleX(1.75) scaleY(1.8); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(360deg) scaleX(1.75) scaleY(1.8);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

    <div id="boxes">
        <div id="box">
            <img src="" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div id="box">
            <img  style="width:100%; height: 100%">
        </div>

        <div id="box">
            <img src="" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="boxes2">
        <div id="box">
            <img src="" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div id="box">
            <img src="" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
        </div>
    </div>
```